# Blank screen when I try to start a GNOME Wayland session

Tags: gnome, lubuntu, wayland

I selected GNOME Wayland and only a blank screen came up. How can I log out from it and select the normal Ubuntu X session?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that rebooting doesn't take you back to the login screen where you can just reselect a Ubuntu session...

I haven't needed to do this myself, but this should work...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type:

  - `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`
  - select **lightdm** as the display manager and hit ok
  - `reboot`
- re-select a Ubuntu session at the login prompt

Comment: İ cannot open grub menu, i have holded shift key, both leftand right, and still no luck

Comment: See if you can go to a tty from your 'blank' screen, `ctrl+alt+F1` or `ctrl+alt+F3` I'd try the F3 first.

Comment: Right now it is stuck at /dev/sda2:clean @heynnema

Comment: And all you did was to choose GNOME Wayland, correct? You didn't change any configuration files like /etc/fstab, or anything else. Try the keys doug mentions. Your keyboard may require that you also press the fn key along with ctrl+alt+F2. If that doesn't work, try alt+F2, or alt+fn+F2 and see what you get. I really would like to get to the GRUB menu... otherwise we're gonna be in a world of hurt.